# Laravel relation doesn't work with leftJoin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, request

I have this criteria (NearCreteria) in Laravel,

```
public function apply($model, RepositoryInterface $repository)
{
    if ($this->request->has(['zone'])) {
        $zone = $this->request->get('zone');

        return $model
            ->leftJoin('zones_delivery', 'restaurants.zone_id', '=', 'zones_delivery.primary_zone')            
            ->where("zones_delivery.secondary_zone", $zone)
            ->orderBy('closed');
    } else {
        return $model->orderBy('closed');
    }
}
```

when I send request parameter "zone" I get correct results, but when I try to get results of "with" parameter or any other relation eloquent, I always get empty array.

for example:

```
http://.../api/restaurants?with=galleries
```

returns each restaurant with it's galleries array filled as requested

```
http://.../api/restaurants?zone=2&with=galleries
```

returns each restaurant with empty galleries but with correct zone = 2.

table relations:
restaurants.zone_id => zones.id => zones_delivery.secondary_zone_id
gallery.restaurant_id => restaurants.id

restaurant.index

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $this->restaurantRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
        $this->restaurantRepository->pushCriteria(new LimitOffsetCriteria($request));
        $this->restaurantRepository->pushCriteria(new RestaurantsOfCuisinesCriteria($request));
        if ($request->has('popular')) {
            $this->restaurantRepository->pushCriteria(new PopularCriteria($request));
        } else {
            $this->restaurantRepository->pushCriteria(new NearCriteria($request));            
        }
        $this->restaurantRepository->pushCriteria(new ActiveCriteria());
        $restaurants = $this->restaurantRepository->all();

    } catch (RepositoryException $e) {
        return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $this->sendResponse($restaurants->toArray(), 'Restaurants retrieved successfully');
}
```

Comment: Relation query builder and join dont mix well. use `whereHas()` instead.

Comment: Yes, do this with a relationship, they are there to avoid having to worry about underlying SQL calls like `JOIN`.

Comment: I tried adding zones_delivery relationship hasMany(), but failed to
 ->where("zones_delivery.secondary_zone", $zone)
I get error zones_delivery.secondary_zone unknown column